# Проблема с отрисовкой CSS-анимации в разных браузерах

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Была написана @keyframes-анмация для плавного появления поля поиска из центра экрана.

```
@keyframes Open{
 0%{
  width: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100%{
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes Open{
 0%{
  width: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100%{
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
html, body{
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.searchbar{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 12px;
    z-index: 5002;
    height: 50px;
    width: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

При воспроизведении через стационарные браузеры Firefox 32 и Opera 36 анимация отрисовывается корректно. Однако, при попытке воспроизведения в мобильных Chrome 67 и Opera 45, отрисовка начинается у правой границы экрана и элемент также располагается возле неё. Также проводил тесты в стандартном мобильном браузере Meizu -  воспроизводится точно такой же **@-webkit-keyframes**, но отрисовывается анимация корректно. При этом, если в параметрах обоих ключевых кадров **@keyframes** убрать свойства **margin-left** и **margin-right**, то анимация в мобильных Chrome и Opera будет воспроизводиться корректно. Однако, в таком случае, в стационарных браузерах отрисовка будет начинаться от левой границы экрана и элемент будет располагаться возле неё.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что могло послужить причиной такого странного поведения анимации в разных браузерах.

[image: Отрисовка в Opera]

[image: Отрисовка в Chrome]

[image: Отрисовка в стандартном браузере Meizu]

UPD: обновил параметры анимации как советовал Геннадий. В мобильных браузерах отображается корректно, в десктопном Firefox 32 тоже, но в десктопной Opera наблюдается следующая картина.

```
@keyframes Open{
    0%{
        width: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
   100%{
       width: 80%;
       opacity: 1;
    }
}
html, body{
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.searchbar{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    border-radius: 12px;
    z-index: 5002;
    height: 50px;
    width: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

[image: Десктопная Opera]

UPD2: по совету Геннадия изменил параметры позиционирования. Всё работает корректно.

[Ссылка на Codepen](https://codepen.io/p1xelguard/pen/RJQKdO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function overlayOpen() {
  $('.overlay').css({
    'opacity': '0.8'
  });
}

function overlayClose() {
  $('.overlay').css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
}

function searchbarOpen() {
  $('.searchbar').css({
    'animation': 'Open 0.6s linear forwards',
    'display': 'flex'
  });
  $('body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden'
  });
  $('.overlay').css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
  setTimeout(overlayOpen, 100);
}

function searchbarClose() {
  $('.searchbar').css({
    'animation': '',
    'display': 'none'
  });
  $('body').css({
    'overflow': 'auto'
  });
  $('.overlay').css({
    'opacity': '0'
  });
  setTimeout(overlayClose, 800);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.searchbarOpenButton').click(searchbarOpen);
  $('.searchbarCloseButton').click(searchbarClose);
});
```

```css
@keyframes Open {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 80%;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes Open {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 80%;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 10%;
  }
}

* {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

body {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #62727b;
  fill: #62727b;
}

header {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 5000;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #444;
}

.sidebarOpenIcon {
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.sidebarOpenButton:hover .sidebarOpenIcon {
  fill: #102027;
}

.sidebarOpenButton {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}

.sidebarOpenButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.head {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 36px;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  cursor: default;
  color: #102027;
}

.searchbarOpenIcon {
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.searchbarOpenButton:hover .searchbarOpenIcon {
  fill: #102027;
}

.searchbarOpenButton {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}

.searchbarOpenButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 5001;
  transition: 0.8s;
  background: #000;
  overflow-y: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}

.searchbar {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  z-index: 5002;
  height: 50px;
  width: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.searchbarSubmit {
  display: none;
}

.searchbarSubmitButton {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}

.searchbarSubmitButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchSubmitIcon {
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.searchbarSubmitButton:hover .searchSubmitIcon {
  fill: #102027
}

.searchbarInput {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: none;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #62727b;
}

.searchbarInput:focus {
  border-color: #102027;
}

.searchbarCloseButton {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}

.searchbarCloseButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchbarCloseIcon {
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.searchbarCloseButton:hover .searchbarCloseIcon {
  fill: #102027;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="sidebarOpenButton">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
        <path class="sidebarOpenIcon" d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="head">
    Проект
  </div>
  <div class="searchbarOpenButton">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
     <path class="searchbarOpenIcon" d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
     <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="overlay">
</div>
<div class="searchbar">
  <div class="searchbarCloseButton">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
     <path class="searchbarCloseIcon" d="M20 11H7.83l5.59-5.59L12 4l-8 8 8 8 1.41-1.41L7.83 13H20v-2z"/>
     <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <input class="searchbarInput" type="search" placeholder="Поиск" name="searchInput">
  <label class="searchbarSubmitButton">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
     <path class="searchSubmitIcon" d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
    <input class="searchbarSubmit" type="submit" name="searchSubmit">
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: да, с такими параметрами в мобильных браузерах отрисовка происходит корректно, но при этом у меня ломается отрисовка в десктопных браузерах

Comment: Проверил свой пример в Chrome,Firefox и IE. Всё в порядке. Создайте в вопросе воспроизводимый пример вашей проблемы. Может быть влияют стили самого блока.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Там ещё ссылка на весь код на Codepen висит - специально прикрепил чтоб можно было воспроизвести.

Comment: Не заметил ссылку на codeopen. Проблема была из-за `position:fixed`. С ним лучше работать через свойства (`top,left,bottom,right` а не через `margin`). Проверьте у себя.

Comment: Да, спасибо, отрисовка происходит корректно